# Erro "exited, floating point exception" em C

Tags: c

Resolvi esse exercício mas ele continua dando o erro "exited, floating point exception", vi que esse problema pode ser causado por divisão por zero... mas não acho o erro, se alguem puder me ajudar...

> Escreva um programa que leia um conjunto de dados contendo altura e sexo (masculino e feminino) de 5 pessoas e depois calcule e escreva:

- a maior e a menor altura do grupo
- a media de alturas das mulheres
- numero de homens e a diferença percentual entre esses e as mulheres

#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
char sexo[5];
float altura[5], maiorAltura=altura[0], menorAltura=altura[0]; float mediaAltMulheres, diferencaPerc=0;
int sexoFem=0, sexoMasc=0;

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
  printf("Sexo: ");
  scanf("%c", &sexo[i]);

  printf("Altura: ");
  scanf("%f", &altura[i]);
  getc(stdin); //impedir erro de buffer

  //maior altura
  if(altura[i]>maiorAltura){
    maiorAltura=altura[i];
  };

  //menor altura
  if(altura[i]<menorAltura){
    menorAltura=altura[i];
  };

  //soma de altura de mulheres
  if(strcmp(sexo, "f")==0){
    sexoFem+=1;
    mediaAltMulheres+=altura[i];
  } else if(strcmp(sexo, "m")==0){
    sexoMasc+=1;
  } 
}

//media de altura de mulheres
mediaAltMulheres=(mediaAltMulheres/sexoFem);

//diferença percentual
if(sexoMasc>sexoFem){
  diferencaPerc=((sexoMasc-sexoFem)/sexoFem)*100;
} else{
  diferencaPerc=((sexoFem-sexoMasc)/sexoMasc)*100;
}

printf("\nA maior altura é %f", maiorAltura);
printf("\nA menor altura é %f", menorAltura);
printf("\nO numero de homens é %d, e a diferença percentual é %f%%", sexoMasc, diferencaPerc);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há três erros lógicos no seu programa.

**Comparar char como se fosse String**

```
if(strcmp(sexo, "f")==0){
    sexoFem+=1;
    mediaAltMulheres+=altura[i];
} else if(strcmp(sexo, "m")==0){
    sexoMasc+=1;
}
```

Nesse trecho de código há um erro lógico, pois você está comparando um char como se fosse uma `string`. A função `strcmp` serve para comparar duas `strings` e não variáveis do tipo `char`.

Na primeira leitura quando você faz `strcmp(sexo, "f")==0`, você verifica se a `string/vetor` `sexo` é igual a `f`, ou seja, se todos os caracteres do vetor `sexo` é igual e na mesma sequencia de `f`. Quando só temos 1 único caractere nesse vetor isso até pode ser verdade (caso a posição `sexo[1]` seja `\0`), mas quando você adiciona mais um elemento ao vetor então o `if` sempre será falso. Exemplo:

Se tem a apenas uma posição então a comparação é assim:

> "f" == "f"

Isso é verdade, mas quando adicionamos mais um elemento então ficará assim:

> "fm" == "f"

E isso é falso, mais um leitura e a string ficará assim:

> "fmf"

Repare que por causa disso o `if` só será ativado uma única vez, logo `sexoMasc` ou `sexoFem` ficará igual a zero enquanto o outro ficará igual a um (você pode até colocar um `printf` depois da leitura para observar isso).

Para resolver isso você precisa comparar a posição do vetor `sexo` que acabou de receber `f` ou `m`, ficando assim:

```
if(sexo[i] == 'f'){
    sexoFem+=1;
    mediaAltMulheres+=altura[i];
} else if(sexo[i] == 'm'){
    sexoMasc+=1;
}
```

`sexo[i] == 'f'` essa é a forma correta de comparar `char`.

**Atribuição de lixo de memória para uma variável**

Repare nesse trecho do código:

```
float altura[5], maiorAltura=altura[0], menorAltura=altura[0];
```

Você criou um vetor de tamanho 5 e deixou `maiorAltura` e `menorAltura` igual a primeira posição de `altura`, mas a pergunta é: qual o valor de `altura[0]`?

Onde estou rodando o código o valor `altura[0]` é sempre zero e isso causa um erro lógico no programa.

Observe que como a `menorAltura` inicia em zero então a menor altura mostrada sempre vai ser zero, pois todos os valores digitados sempre vão ser na faixa de 1.5 a 2 (e zero de fato é menor que esses valores). Mas vamos supor que o valor de `altura[0]` for `645456`, então o erro será em `maiorAltura`. Por causa disso não podemos fazer aquela atribuição, deixe o código assim:

```
float altura[5], maiorAltura, menorAltura;
```

Isso ainda não resolve o problema, pois as variáveis ainda estão com lixo de memória.

Para resolver o problema podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("Sexo: ");
    scanf("%c", &sexo[i]);

    printf("Altura: ");
    scanf("%f", &altura[i]);
    getc(stdin); //impedir erro de buffer

    if(i == 0)
    {
        maiorAltura = altura[i];
        menorAltura = altura[i];
    }
    else
    {
        //maior altura
        if(altura[i] > maiorAltura)
        {
            maiorAltura = altura[i];
        }

        //menor altura
        if(altura[i] < menorAltura)
        {
            menorAltura = altura[i];
        }
    }
    // Resto do código
```

Repare o novo `if` só será ativado na primeira leitura, então `menorAltura` e `maiorAltura` serão iguais a `altura[0]` (a diferença agora é que essa posição do vetor não tem mais lixo e sim um valor válido para o nosso programa). Da segunda leitura em diante o `else` sempre será ativado e com isso o programa vai comparar os tamanhos.

**Erro ao calcular a porcentagem**

Outro erro no seu programa é:

```
//diferença percentual
if(sexoMasc > sexoFem) {
  diferencaPerc = ((sexoMasc - sexoFem) / sexoFem) * 100;
} else {
  diferencaPerc = (( sexoFem - sexoMasc) / sexoMasc) * 100;
}
```

Repare que primeiro o programa vai subtrair dois inteiros (`sexoMasc` e `sexoFem`), vamos supor que foi digitados 3 homens e duas mulheres, então `sexoMasc - sexoFem`:

> 3 - 2 = 1

Como as duas variáveis são do tipo `int` então a resposta também vai ser `int`. Agora vamos dividir a resposta (que é do tipo `int`) por 2:

> 1 / 2 = 0

Quando dividimos um inteiro a resposta também é um inteiro e a parte decimal é perdida,  isso está ocorrendo no seu código. Para que a resposta seja `0,5` o `1` teria que ser do tipo `float` (repare que ele não é pois é resultado de dois `int`, sendo assim ele é `int`).

Para resolver esse problema poderiamos mudar o tipo das variáveis `sexoMasc` e `sexoFem`. Mas há uma outra forma, podemos usar o `(float)` para dizer que o resultado da soma deve ser do tipo `float`, dessa forma:

```
diferencaPerc = ((float)(sexoMasc - sexoFem) / (sexoFem)) * 100;
```

Aqui estamos dizendo que o resultado da soma deve ser `float` `(float)(sexoMasc - sexoFem)`.

Seu código fica assim com as alterações citadas:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char sexo[5];
    float altura[5], maiorAltura, menorAltura;
    float mediaAltMulheres, diferencaPerc = 0;
    int sexoFem = 0, sexoMasc = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Sexo: ");
        scanf("%c", &sexo[i]);

        printf("Altura: ");
        scanf("%f", &altura[i]);
        getc(stdin); //impedir erro de buffer

        if(i == 0)
        {
            maiorAltura = altura[i];
            menorAltura = altura[i];
        }
        else
        {
            //maior altura
            if(altura[i] > maiorAltura)
            {
                maiorAltura = altura[i];
            }

            //menor altura
            if(altura[i] < menorAltura)
            {
                menorAltura = altura[i];
            }
        }

        //soma de altura de mulheres
        //if(strcmp(sexo, "f") == 0)
        if(sexo[i] == 'f')
        {
            sexoFem += 1;
            mediaAltMulheres += altura[i];
        }
        //else if(strcmp(sexo, "m") == 0)
        else if(sexo[i] == 'm')
        {
            sexoMasc += 1;
        } 
    }

    //media de altura de mulheres
    mediaAltMulheres = (mediaAltMulheres / sexoFem);

    //diferença percentual
    if(sexoMasc > sexoFem)
    {
        diferencaPerc = ((float)(sexoMasc - sexoFem) / (sexoFem)) * 100;
    }
    else
    {
        diferencaPerc = ((float)(sexoFem - sexoMasc) / sexoMasc) * 100;
    }

    printf("\nA maior altura é %f", maiorAltura);
    printf("\nA menor altura é %f", menorAltura);
    printf("\nO numero de homens é %d, e a diferença percentual é %f%%", sexoMasc, diferencaPerc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!!